# <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> not working in oracle database and in mysql it works

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml file,hbm2ddl.auto property is set to update,and if table is not present in my database it is not creating table.hbm2ddl.auto create is working fine.

50

```
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property> 
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl</property> 
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property> <property 
            name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property> <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property> 
            <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">3</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">3</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryDelay">1000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts">60</property>

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">3</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">14400</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">select 1</property>

        <property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
         <mapping resource="STUDENT.hbm.xml" /> 
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Which version of hibernate are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There are some known problems with the functionality of update in some versions of hibernate using Oracledb, try to use version 5.0 or to those after 5.1.4

> https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12059?focusedCommentId=100201&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel
>
> [Why hbm2ddl.auto 'update' property is not working or how does it works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47179449/why-hbm2ddl-auto-update-property-is-not-working-or-how-does-it-works)